# VS Code not showing subfolders when there is only one

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS Code is not showing the sub folders when there is only one folder, it only shows when there is 2 or more. I attached a screenshot to show an example. I would like to make it show all the folders. I have been looking for how to make it go back to showing all the folders but could not find how.

[image: vs code screenshot]

If I add more folders it goes back to normal. I would to make it show the Search folder even if it is the only folder inside Input.

[image]

Comment: It is showing your folders, but they're empty, hence the crumbs.

Comment: They are not. Input folder has a Search folder and Search folder has 2 files. When I click on Input folder it does not not Search folder, instead it shows it like this: Input/Search.

Comment: Is there a file (as opposed to a folder) in the Input folder? If Input is devoid of files, this would be considered a convenience, I suppose.

Comment: It may be for some, but for me it is super annoying. I would see to see all my folders. And this only happens if Input contains only one folder, if I add more folders it goes back to normal. I will add a screenshot.

Comment: yeah, I get it. Shrug! Maybe file an issue over on [https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode)VSCode

Comment: I will do that, thanks.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue, I figured out how to disable this. You need to look up explorer.compactFolders in File > Preference > Settings and disable it.

Comment: I did that and it made no difference - still can't see sub folders

Answer (score 20):

That's explained in [November 2019 (version 1.41) release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41). The feature is called [Compact folders in Explorer](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_compact-folders-in-explorer):

> In the File Explorer, we now render single child folders in a compact
>   form. In such a form, single child folders will be compressed in a
>   combined tree element. Useful for Java package structures, for
>   example.
>
> Setting `explorer.compactFolders` controls this behavior. By default,
>   this setting is turned on.